# Using pygame in macOS High Sierra (beta 3)

Tags: python, macos, pygame, 32-bit, macos-high-sierra

As I understand, High Sierra only supports 64 bit applications. The workaround to use pygame in Mac is to install the 32 bit version of Python, as this library only works with that version.

When I install the 32 bit version of Python I can't open IDLE. Opening the app only makes the icon appear and dissappear instantly in the dock bar.

Is there any other way to get pygame working in this situation?

**EDIT**

Ok, using another IDE, like PyCharm, did the trick for now.

Comment: So do you still have a problem that needs answering? If you have resolved your problem please consider deleting your question OR post a solution as an answer.

Comment: @Alex I found a workaround but I haven't solved the original issue yet. Can't use the official IDE on High Sierra in its 32 bit version.